# Инсталлятор для проекта

Tags: php, yii2, composer

Возник такой вопрос - у меня есть проект на **yii2**, проект достаточно объемный

Так-же нужен инсталлятор (в компании иногда нужно создавать его копии), так как я не всегда имею возможность самостоятельно развернуть проект в новой среде ввиду командировки.

Инсталлятор, в котором будут задаваться все параметры я напишу, но вот как быть с **vendor**.

Дело в том что весь проект, вместе с vendor-директорией  240мб, без нее 40 мб.

Как лучше запихнуть в инсталлятор установку всех библиотек через **composer** ( при условии что его может не быть в разворачиваемой среде )?

Comment: Обычно папка `vendor` не хранится и при разворачивании проекта все устанавливается из `composer`. Главное чтоб был `composer.lock`, иначе зависимости могут нарушиться (особенно если проект не новый.)

Comment: Это я знаю. Вопрос в другом-же.

Comment: извиняюсь, не так понял похоже. Тогда я бы предложил просто добавить к установщику `composer.phar`, весит всего 1.8мб. Можно даже не проверять есть ли установленный `composer`, а распаковывать файл в любом случае (ничего не сломает, если он уже установлен) и запускать `php composer.phar install` в корне проекта из установщика.

Comment: @RTK ну кстати как вариант)))

Answer (score 0):

Кажется ты дорос до использования docker. Скорее всего это то, что нужно. При его использовании на сервере должен быть установлен только ssh, чтобы подключиться, сам docker и docker-compose. Больше ничего не надо.

Выглядит все это примерно так:

1. Клонируем репозиторий
2. Разворачиваем проект
3. Запускаем проект

Чтобы все это уложилось в три команды, конечно же, придется немного повозиться и настроить контейнеры докера, установку пакетов через composer, инициализацию проекта и т.д.

Как [установить докер](https://www.8host.com/blog/ustanovka-i-ispolzovanie-docker-v-ubuntu-18-04/). При этом на 18 убунте не должно быть своего докера или его надо удалить, он там старый из коробки.

[Установка docker-compose](https://www.8host.com/blog/ustanovka-i-ispolzovanie-docker-compose-na-ubuntu-14-04/) там же хорошо описана.

Comment: Докер я знаю и он мне не подходит.

Comment: Чем же он не подходит?

Comment: Как-раз потому что часто vds на 18 убунте созают (не я)

Comment: Это не проблема. Я в первый раз тоже ошибок хватанул. Надо устанавливать без докера, либо потом его сразу удалить. Сейчас на 18 норм работаю.

Comment: Ну вот я без докера и хочу.